# density of {nx+m} but in general case

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a problem, suppose that $\{t_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive numbers increasing to $\infty$. Then there is a large set $S$ of real numbers such that if you take $x\in S$ then the set $\{t_nx+m \mid n\geq 1,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I could solve this for particular type of $t_n$, such as  $t_n=n$ for example,  but I'm not getting any idea how to do for general case. Please someone help me out.